# How to Make Dynamic Forms Between Two Models Ruby on Rails 3+

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am searching for two days and still can't make a form using two models , and I didn't understand anything from the FormHelper View, It is not useful for me , Is this the only way to make a dynamic form between two models in rails 3.2 ? this video for an old version of rails :( Really I don't know what to do..

Is this Episode can be used in rails 3.2 ??
http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus

**I need a detailed example please****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for `fields_for` - http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for.

Comment: Please I need more explain by examples because I can't get it from FormHelper , reading makes me confused and can't understand what's going on :D

Comment: Maybe you can explain the relationship between the two models you are trying to represent in the form...

Comment: Thanks anyway for your answer, I will try to make as wrote in FormHelper and will post another question if i am facing errors , sorry i am a newbie :(

Comment: I will look for your help in my next question ! thanks